# scikit-learn pipeline strategy with both numeric and categorical columns

Tags: scikit-learn, pipelines

We are implementing an `sklearn pipeline` as follows (pseudo code):

```
feature_num = numeric_columns  
feature_cat = categorical_columns  

num_pipeline = Pipeline([('feature_select', DataFrameSelector(feature_num))
                        ,('feature_num_prep', custom_num_prep)
                       ])  
cat_pipeline = Pipeline([('feature_select', DataFrameSelector(feature_cat))
                        ,('feature_cat_prep', custom_cat_prep)
                       ])  
feature_pipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
                               ('num_pipeline', num_pipeline)
                               ,('cat_pipeline', cat_pipeline)
])
```

Since we have in the `custom_num_prep` transformer the possibility to remove outliers - when we get to the feature_pipeline there is an error:

> ValueError: [blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions....

The reason is obvious since the `cat_pipeline` has observations that the `num_pipeline` has removed.
The question is:
1. is there a pythonic way to sync the two dataframes within the pipelines?
2. if not what strategy is there for such situations?

Answer (score 2):

One option is scikit-learn's [ColumnTransformer applied to mixed types](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html). ColumnTransformer is designed for the purpose of applying different preprocessing and feature extraction pipelines to different subsets of the features.